# how to set data from fromgroup angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

I have a problem in set data from object to fromgroup
file TS

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { DemandeConges } from 'src/app/models/ui-models/Demande_Conges';
import { CongesService } from '../../conges.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, RequiredValidator, Validators } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-print',
  templateUrl: './print.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./print.component.scss']
})
export class PrintComponent implements OnInit {
  show: boolean = false;
  url: string='';
  report: string='';
   AllDemande: any=[];
  private id: number=0;
  private sub: any;
  errorMsg: String='';
  isRequestEdit = false;
  selectedLeaveRequest!: DemandeConges;

  isLeaveRequestSelected = false;
  selected_leave_msg: String='';
  requestApproveForm !: FormGroup;
  has_error = false;
  approve_leave_update_msg: String='';
  submitted = false;

demandeCongeId:string|null|undefined;
Demandes: any=[];


  constructor(private readonly congeService:CongesService,private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private readonly route: ActivatedRoute) {



    }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(
      (params) => {
        this.demandeCongeId=params.get('id');
        if(this.demandeCongeId){

          this.congeService.DemandeConge(this.demandeCongeId)
          .subscribe(
            (successResponse)=> {
              this.AllDemande=successResponse
              this.Demandes=successResponse
              console.log(this.AllDemande);
              console.log(this.Demandes.id)

            });
      } });


  }

    }
    initRequestApproveForm() {

         this.requestApproveForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          Id: [this.demandeCongeId],
          reason: [this.AllDemande.Reason],
          status: [this.AllDemande.status, Validators.required],

        });

       // this.requestApproveForm.get('alternate')?.patchValue(this.Demandes.alternate);
      //this.requestApproveForm.controls["alternate"].setValue(this.AllDemande.get('alternate'))

      // this.requestApproveForm.controls['alternate'].patchValue(122);
      // this.requestApproveForm.patchValue({ alternate: this.AllDemande.id });
      // this.requestApproveForm.controls['alternate'].setValue(this.AllDemande.reason);





        console.log(this.AllDemande)



      console.log(this.requestApproveForm.value)
    }
    toggleEdit() {
      this.isRequestEdit = !this.isRequestEdit;
      this.initRequestApproveForm();
    }
    get f() { return this.requestApproveForm.controls; }

    onSubmit(){

 console.log(this.requestApproveForm.value)
      this.submitted = true;
      // stop here if form is invalid
      if (this.requestApproveForm.invalid) {
        return;
      }
      console.log('success ', this.requestApproveForm.value);
      // this.requestApproveForm.patchValue({
      //   leaveId
      // });
      this.congeService.updateDemandeConges(this.demandeCongeId,this.requestApproveForm.value).subscribe(res => {
        this.has_error = false;
        this.approve_leave_update_msg = 'Successfully Submitted';
        this.requestApproveForm.reset();
        this.AllDemande=res;
        this.submitted = false;
      })
    }
}
```

**function for submit form**

```
onSubmit(){
this.congeService.updateDemandeConges(this.demandeCongeId,this.requestApproveForm.value).subscribe(res => {
        this.has_error = false;
        this.approve_leave_update_msg = 'Successfully Submitted';
        this.requestApproveForm.reset();
        this.AllDemande=res;
        this.submitted = false;
      })
```

file HTML

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 ">

        <div class="profile-head">
            <h5><span class="font-weight-bold text-success">
              <a routerLink="/home/employees/details/">
            </a>
            </span>
              </h5>
              <h1 class="display-3">Nom et Prénom     : {{item.employeeNom}} {{item.employeePrenom}} </h1>
              <h3>Date de la Demande :{{item.created_AT|date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}} <span></span></h3>
              </div>
        </div>
        </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 ">


          <button class="btn btn-info float-right" (click)="toggleEdit()">
            {{isRequestEdit ? "Afficher la Demande" : "Approbation de la demande"}}
          </button>

      </div>
      <div mat-tab-nav-bar class="custom-tab">
        <a mat-tab-link class="nav-link active">Info</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="col-md-6 border-right ">
          <h3 class="pl-2">LeaveRequest Id   : {{item.id}} </h3>
          <h3 class="pl-2">Employee       : {{item.employeeNom}} {{item.employeePrenom}} </h3>
          <h3 class="pl-2">Type de Congé    : {{item.typeCongesId}}  </h3>
          <h3 class="pl-2" >Nombre des jours    : {{item.nmbJours}} Jours</h3>
          <h3 class="pl-2">Date début du congé   : {{item.from_Date|date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</h3>
          <h3 class="pl-2">Date Fin du congé     : {{item.to_Date|date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}} </h3>
          <h3 class="pl-2">Status  :{{item.status}}</h3>
          <h3 class="pl-2" FormControlName="alternate">Alternative  :{{item.alternate}}</h3>
          <h3 class="pl-2">Coordonnées  :{{item.details}}</h3>
        </div>
        <button (click)="Clicked(item.id)">Télécharger la Demande</button>
            <div *ngIf="show">
            <iframe id="report" height="1000" width="10" [src]="url | safeUrl"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>


      <div class="col-sm-1">

        <div class="d-flex" style="height: 360px;">
          <div class="vr"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">


        <div *ngIf="isRequestEdit" class="col-md-9">

          <form [formGroup]="requestApproveForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" >

            <!-- <div *ngIf="!!approve_leave_update_msg" [ngClass]="has_error ? 'alert alert-danger': 'alert alert-info'">{{approve_leave_update_msg}}</div> -->

            <h5 class="text-center text-info mb-4"> Approve Request </h5>
            <div class="form-group row" >
              <label for="status" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" >Status &nbsp;<span class="text-danger">* </span></label>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <mat-radio-group id="status" formControlName="status" class="custom-ngSelect">
                  <mat-radio-button value="APPROUVÉ">APPROUVÉ</mat-radio-button>
                  <mat-radio-button class="pl-2" value="REFUSÉ">REFUSÉ</mat-radio-button>
                </mat-radio-group>

              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="reason" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Reason&nbsp;</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" id="reason" formControlName="reason" class="form-control" class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Reason" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="mt-3 btn-block" type="submit">Submit </button>
          </form>
          </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    </div>
```

When I add data on the form a have 3 properties I want to have all properties of object to update data on database and other properties come from object with name **AllDemande**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvyYI.jpg)
and the form has 3 properties I want to complete all properties for object
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the property for set to a form group is `this.requestApproveForm.controls["fieldName"].setValue()`
but we need more information to help you more.

if is for the part of code you have commented you forgot to init the alternate field in the form :

```
this.requestApproveForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      Id: [this.demandeCongeId],
      reason: [this.AllDemande.Reason],
      status: [this.AllDemande.status, Validators.required],
      alternate: ['']
    });
```

Comment: `this.requestApproveForm.patchValue({ [controlName]: controlValue })` to update multiple controls

Comment: what information you need

Comment: it a reply for the anser abrove. you need to init alternate when your create the formGroup `alternate: ['']`

Comment: i intial it by alternate:[''] but it retrun undefiend

Answer (score 0):

when I add this line of code I have this error

```
 initRequestApproveForm() {

         this.requestApproveForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          Id: [this.demandeCongeId],
          reason: [this.AllDemande.Reason],
          status: [this.AllDemande.status, Validators.required],
        });
        this.requestApproveForm.controls["alternate"].setValue(this.AllDemande.alternate )


      console.log(this.requestApproveForm.value)
    }
```

[image]

Comment: and when i set the value manuely it work